# Not able a connect to Datastax Cassandra with Spring boot version 2.3.0.Release

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-astra

I am not able to establish a connection with the datastax cassandra instance with spring boot version 2.3.0.RELEASE. **The same code works fine with spring boot 2.6 version.**

Error while running the spring boot app

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': \
  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; \
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: \
  Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: \
  Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: \
  Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: \
  Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; \
  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: \
    Can't use withCloudSecureConnectBundle and explicitly specify ssl configuration. They are mutually exclusive.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        ...
```

```
@Configuration
public class CassandraConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
    private String contactPoints;

    @Value("${astra.secure-connect-bundle:none}")
    private String astraSecureConnectBundle;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}")
    private String cassandraUsername;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}")
    private String cassandraPassword;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
    private String keySpace;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter}")
    private String dataCenter;

    @Bean
    public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer sessionBuilderCustomizer() {
        /*
         * When using DataStax Astra, we must pass the secure connect bundle to the
         * CqlSession
         * See documentation:
         * https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/aws/doc/dscloud/astra/dscloudUsingDrivers.
         * html
         */
        if (!astraSecureConnectBundle.equals("none")) {
            return builder -> builder
                    .withCloudSecureConnectBundle(Paths
                            .get("C:/projects/****/****/**/secure-connect-###.zip"))//zip file provided by datastax
                    .withAuthCredentials(this.cassandraUsername, this.cassandraPassword);
        } else {
            return builder -> builder
                    .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress(this.contactPoints, this.port))
                    .withLocalDatacenter(this.dataCenter)
                    .withAuthCredentials(this.cassandraUsername, this.cassandraUsername);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer driverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer() {
        /*
         * When using DataStax Astra, we do not have to pass contact points like we
         * normally would because
         * this metadata is contained in the secure connect bundle.
         */
        if (!astraSecureConnectBundle.equals("none")) {
            return builder -> builder.without(DefaultDriverOption.CONTACT_POINTS);
        }
        return builder -> builder
                .withString(DefaultDriverOption.SESSION_NAME, "spring-boot-service");
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name="KeySpaceSpace"
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=#########.db.astra.datastax.com
spring.data.cassandra.port=32392
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=dc-1
spring.data.cassandra.username=###########
spring.data.cassandra.password=###########
spring.data.cassandra.ssl=true
astra.secure-connect-bundle=${ASTRA_SECURE_CONNECT_BUNDLE:/app/astra/creds}
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.6.0</version> -->
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-one-poc-svc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sample-one-poc-svc</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1 </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1 </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-driver-query-builder</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-driver-mapper-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-driver-mapper-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am not sure if it is the same issue as this
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21487
The issue says its fixedin 2.3.1 version of spring boot, but I aget same exception if I use 2.3.1 version.

Comment: underlying error is : Can't use withCloudSecureConnectBundle and explicitly specify ssl configuration. They are mutually exclusive. Did you try remove the ssl=true property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew is on the right track with his comment. The problem is that the secure connect bundle contains connection metadata plus SSL (TLS) credentials so the driver already expects that encryption is enabled which is the reason the resolver throws this exception:

```
  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: \
    Can't use withCloudSecureConnectBundle and explicitly specify ssl configuration. \
    They are mutually exclusive.
```

You can resolve the conflict by removing this line from `application.properties`:

```
spring.data.cassandra.ssl=true
```

I'm not familiar with the Spring code base so I'm not able verify why it works in 2.6 but not 2.3.

Credit to Cédric Lunven for pointers on the issue. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks . It works with turning ssl =false